# Angular DevExtreme GMapsAPI key changes in production

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, devextreme

I'm working on an Angular 6 app, which uses the DevExtreme map component `dx-map`.

The component allows the usage of two providers: 'Bing' and 'Google Maps'.
When using GMaps, an API key needs to be provided.

So this is how I provide the key in the TS file:

`public mapProvider = { provider: 'google', key: environment.googleMapsKey };`

And this is the HTML part:

`<dx-map #map [provider]="mapProvider.provider" [key]="mapProvider.key"></dx-map>`

When working within the dev env, locally with `ng s`, everything works like a charm.
Inspecting the network calls, the key is correct, and points to the `dev` one.

The strange part comes when we move to production... But first I've done some tests to ensure that is not something stupid from my side:

- command: `ng s` the **dev** api key **is used**
- command: `ng s --prod` the **dev** api key **is used**
- command: `ng b --aot --prod && cd dist/project && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000` the **dev** api key **is used**
- Upload the `dist` on Amazon s3 and access the application through CloudFront and BOOM. **A different key is used**

The strange thing is that the key in question, isn't present in my code, neither hardcoded, neither in the env files and neither on my project on the Google Cloud Console...

This makes me think that is a "default" key used? When in production? By who? Google? Devextreme?

I can't wrap my head around this, and I don't even know what to search for...

The message that comes out is the following:

`js?callback=_googleScriptReady&key=AIzaSyBvc9eOh-EXYaHSFbwRzMpW2Q1e_sLUXw8&_=1540745848444:53 You have exceeded your request quota for this API. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors`

Ok, great, thanks Google, even I know that a wrong key was used, but the problem is that I can't understand from where this key comes out and most important: **why**

Here's the screenshot from Google Cloud Console for the specific key: (I apologise but is in Italian)

[image]

Thanks in advance to everyone willing to help.
Caius

### Edit:

Ok something strange is happening... Suddenly without any intervention, and after some hours after the last deploy the map started working normally with the correct key. WTF?

If someone has any valid explanation is welcome

Comment: It's really a strange issue. Can you check your google account for GMap Project have this key configured?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya, what do you mean with google account? If you mean on the Google Cloud Console, everything looks ok. The origin is allowed with `*.cloudfront.net/*`, and the Google Maps API is enabled.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya, I've edited the question adding a screenshot

Comment: Sounds like the key was somehow **cached**, otherwise there aren't enough informations tu guess what happened.

Comment: Still, it's what I thought, but in order for the cache to cache something... that information should exist somewhere... and the "cached" key wasn't declared anywhere...